How to insert literals in a colon definition?
I wrote a Forth interpreter for the J1 CPU, which I am now porting to Z80. In the new version, a colon word is a list of addresses to be called by the interpreter.
My problem is how to insert literals into a colon definition.
Example:
: 1+ 1 + ;

When the compiler encounters literal 1, it has no address to call that push the value onto the stack.
A solution would be to dynamically generate a routine like
ld   hl, 1
push hl
ret

somewhere else and use that address in the colon definition.
Another solution is to use an invalid address (such as 0x0000) followed by the literal, which would be treated as a special case by the interpreter: upon encountering an address 0x0000, it simply pushes the value of the next two bytes onto the stack. In this case, the definition of 1+ would be like this in memory:
0x0000 ;
0x0001 ; literal
0x4500 ; + routine address

Is there a better solution?
Edit
In J1 machine code, the 1+ compile to this
addr code     comments

0125 8001     1   ; Bit 15=1 push literal into stack
0126 628f     %+  ; This combine op codes PLUS and RET


Since this problem is independent of the target CPU: How did you solve it in your former Forth? -- I'm afraid that your question leads to opinionated answers and might be closed thereof.

The J1 is a Forth machine, so words translate directly to machine code. My interpreter compile to machine code, where values are automatically pushed into the stack. See https://www.forth.org/svfig/kk/11-2010-Bowman.pdf

A classic approach is to manipulate the return address:
: (lit) ( -- x ) ( R: addr1 -- addr2 )
  \ NB: "(lit)" should not be used as an ordinary word
  r> dup cell+ >r @
;

: lit, ( x -- )
  ['] (lit) compile, ,
  \ it is assumed that code space
  \ is united with data space 
;
: literal ( x -- x | )
  state @ if lit, then
; immediate

The word (lit) above also known as simple lit. Traditionally, a parenthesized name for a word is used in Forth to emphasize that the word is for internal purposes only.
Let's consider a definition foo:
: foo 42 + ;

Let one cell takes two address units, and the body of foo start at the address 1024. Then the threaded code of the body consists of the following items:

1024: xt of (lit)
1026: the number 42
1028: xt of +
1030: xt of exit

When (lit) is called from foo, the top value on the return stack is 1026. And that's the address where the number 42 is stored. (lit) pops the top value from the return stack (which is 1026), increases its copy by the cell size, and places the result (which is 1028) onto the return stack. It also fetches the value at the address 1026 leaving 42 on the stack. Execution then continues at 1028.
A value that follows an instruction in binary code and on which the instruction's behavior depends is sometimes called "immediate argument" (the immediate argument of the instruction).
An instruction with its immediate argument can be thought as a single instruction of a larger size.
Not only (lit) has an immediate argument. Conditional branch and jump instructions usually have an immediate argument as well.
An alternative approach is to generate an anonymous primitive for every unique pair of an instruction and its immediate argument. I'm not sure if this approach has been used in practice.
See also: Open Interpreter: Portability of Return Stack
Manipulations, M.L.Gassanenko, 1998

I can't see how that works. I'm already compiling a word when a new literal (42 for example) is found. Can you expand?

@CandidMoe, see: Open Interpreter: Portability of Return Stack Manipulations. Let me know if something is unclear.

It looks like I have to rewrote 1+ as : 1+ lit [ 1 , ] + ; , which is ugly. Also, I have the xt of lit; just I don't see where to store the particular value using DTC. There is only on lit, but many values.

Why not : 1+ [ 1 lit, ] + ;?  But it isn't necessary. It's usually done by the Forth text interpreter (or target compiler) under the hood. I have added a particular example how it works.

Yeah, I was thinking along the same lines. It detract from the purity of "list of addresses" implementation, but it works.

Regarding purity of the list of addresses — even without literals it's not so pure: conditional branches and jumps usually have an immediate argument too (I have updated the post).
